# How to build nifi processor nar file and dependencies from maven central

Tags: java, maven, apache-nifi

I am trying to build a nar file from maven repo central. I am not very used to maven, so I will explain the steps I followed until the blocking point where I am stuck now.

I want to generate the nar files for this artifact:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar/1.10.0

So I created this `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TestMaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestMaven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar</artifactId>
                        <version>1.10.0</version>
                </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <!-- hardcode values, or use properties, depending on what you want
                                        to do -->
                                    <groupId>TestMaven</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>TestMaven</artifactId>
                                    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                    <type>[ packaging ]</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <!-- other configurations here -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And then I try to compile whit this commands (first commands are to include maven dependencies on the PATH):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112 
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven 
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin export PATH=$M2:$PATH 
mvn -U -X dependency:copy-dependencies -DskipTests
-Dclassifier=sources -DoutputDirectory=target -Dhttp.proxyHost=X.X.X.X -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=X.X.X.X -Dhttps.proxyPort=80
```

And I am getting this error, which says that the maven dependency couldn't be found:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project TestMaven: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project TestMaven:TestMaven:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could
>   not find artifact
>   org.apache.nifi:nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar:jar:1.10.0 in central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal on project TestMaven: Could not resolve dependencies for
>   project TestMaven:TestMaven:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
>   artifact org.apache.nifi:nifi-hwx-schema-registry-nar:jar:1.10.0 in
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to get the source code for Apache NiFi version 1.10.0 and then build that module.

You could get the code by cloning the git repo and checking out the tag rel/1.10.0.

https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/rel/nifi-1.10.0/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-hwx-schema-registry-bundle

Then run `mvn clean package` from the location above.

Comment: A note atop. Since the project is huge, you may end up facing build failures several times due to connection reset. So, as recommended in Github instructions, use 2.0C along with maven install command. And one more note, you can comment out any nar bundle that may not be of use in the particular context. This can be done by commenting modules in pom.xml under \nifi-1.10\nifi-nar-bundles\

Once done, you can copy the nar files from targets like - \nifi-1.10\nifi-nar-bundles\nifi-*-bundle\nifi-*-nar\target to nifi lib folder and restart Nifi.